# How can I restrict inserting data on behalf of another user in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following code in my django project.

### `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Doctor(models.Model):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=256, unique=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Patient(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

### `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Doctor, Patient

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Doctor

        fields = [
            'name',
            'education'
        ]

class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Patient

        fields = '__all__'
```

### `views.py`

```
from rest_framework import status, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Doctor, Patient
from .serializers import DoctorSerializer, PatientSerializer

class DoctorList(APIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(hospital=request.user)
        serializer = DoctorSerializer(doctors, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = DoctorSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(hospital=request.user)
            return Response({"message": "Doctor inserted!"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class PatientList(APIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        patients = Patient.objects.filter(doctor__hospital=request.user)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patients, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PatientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"message": "Patient inserted!"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

These views are then wired up with endpoints `doctors/` and `patients/` respectively. The problem I am having is restricting the owner (in this case, a hospital, yale or middlesex) from being able to insert a patient on behalf of another doctor. The following screen capture shows that I am logged in as "middlesex", but have the option to insert a patient on behalf of Dr. Bob or Dr. Alice, who ARE associated with the yale hospital (owner), not the Middlesex hospital. How can I fix this so if I am logged in as "middlesex" I will ONLY see Dr. Fred as an option to associate the selected Dr at the hospital with a new patient? Refer to the following image for a better idea of what I am trying to get at. [image]

Comment: Review [DRF permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Can you offer any more support on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) in DRF docs. Please try to  update your `serializers.py` to have filtered doctors based on currently logged user:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Doctor, Patient

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Doctor

        fields = [
            'name',
            'education'
        ]

class FilteredDoctor(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is None:
            return queryset
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = queryset.filter(hospital=request.user)
        return queryset


class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    doctor = FilteredDoctor(
        slug_field="name",
        many=False,
        allow_null=False
    )

    class Meta:

        model = Patient
        fields = ['name', 'doctor']
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! @pplonski